# Find unique properties in array and calculate matching items

Tags: javascript

I want to find matching items in this array using the property `category`, in this app each user can have custom categories so the server cannot know the name of categories prior to running the function.

```
0: {amount: "123", category: "drinks", location: "NYC", note: "piano bar", receipt: "img.jpg", …}
1: {amount: "123", category: "drinks", location: "NYC", note: "piano bar", receipt: "img.jpg", …}
2: {amount: "123", category: "bills", location: "NYC", note: "piano bar", receipt: "img.jpg", …}
3: {amount: "123", category: "savings", location: "NYC", note: "piano bar", receipt: "img.jpg, ...}
```

This my code so far

```
fetch = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    const { currentUser } = fire.auth();
    var stamp = moment().format('LLLL');
    const wallet = fire.database().ref(`/master/${currentUser.uid}/wallets/cash/income/transactions/20190520`);
    wallet.on('value', snapshot => {
      var data = snapshot.val();
      var categories = []
      for (let i in data) {
        categories.push(data[i].category)
      };
      console.log(categories);
      this.setState({ loading: false, ok: true });
    })
  }
```

Here my goal is find all categories in this array and store them in value like `{drinks,bills,savings}` and then see how many items match this category like

- drinks 2
- bills 1
- savings 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get all categories with a count of the number of array elements associated with each one.

```js
const arr = [{ amount: "123", category: "drinks", location: "NYC", note: "piano bar", receipt: "img.jpg" }, { amount: "123", category: "drinks", location: "NYC", note: "piano bar", receipt: "img.jpg" }, { amount: "123", category: "bills", location: "NYC", note: "piano bar", receipt: "img.jpg" }, { amount: "123", category: "savings", location: "NYC", note: "piano bar", receipt: "img.jpg" }];
const categories = arr.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const category = obj.category;
  if (category in acc) {
    acc[category] += 1;
  } else {
    acc[category] = 1;
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(categories);
// { drinks: 2, bills: 1, savings: 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Es6 Map class to store key as category and value as array of matching element. Map provides plenty of methods  as well that you can [check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```
let yourArray = [{
        amount: "123",
        category: "drinks",
        location: "NYC",
        note: "piano bar",
        receipt: "img.jpg"
    },
    {
        amount: "123",
        category: "drinks",
        location: "NYC",
        note: "piano bar",
        receipt: "img.jpg"
    },
    {
        amount: "123",
        category: "bills",
        location: "NYC",
        note: "piano bar",
        receipt: "img.jpg"
    },
    {
        amount: "123",
        category: "savings",
        location: "NYC",
        note: "piano bar",
        receipt: "img.jpg"
    }
]


var newMap = new Map();


yourArray.forEach(ele => {
    if (!newMap.get(ele.category)) {
        newMap.set(ele.category, [ele])
    } else {
        newMap.get(ele.category).push(ele)
    }
})

console.log(newMap)
newMap.forEach((value, key) => {
    console.log(`${key} ${value.length}`)
})
```

Comment: It's a great answer but I like the reduce/accumulator method

Comment: no problem even I like reduce. I find Map more readable so suggested. thanks for appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the for each loop and iterate over them and save the count in  an object

```
    let data = [
{amount: "123", category: "drinks", location: "NYC", note: "piano bar", receipt: "img.jpg"},
{amount: "123", category: "drinks", location: "NYC", note: "piano bar", receipt: "img.jpg"},
{amount: "123", category: "bills", location: "NYC", note: "piano bar", receipt: "img.jpg"},
{amount: "123", category: "savings", location: "NYC", note: "piano bar", receipt: "img.jpg"}];

let countObj = {};
data.forEach((val,ind)=>{
    if(countObj[val.category]){
        countObj[val.category] = countObj[val.category] + 1 ;
  }else{
    countObj[val.category] = 1;
  }
})
console.log(countObj);
```

gives the result

```
bills: 1
drinks: 2
savings: 1
```

Comment: Why it's wrapped inside {count: 1}?

Comment: as for the first time , when we iterate , we get first the category , as we are want the count , i am initializing it to 1

Comment: we can remove the count , it is unnessary added , in the code i have updated

Answer (score 0):

You could use array.includes to see if your value already exists, and count the amount in another array like this:

```
 fetch = () => {
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        const { currentUser } = fire.auth();
        var stamp = moment().format('LLLL');
        const wallet = fire.database().ref(`/master/${currentUser.uid}/wallets/cash/income/transactions/20190520`);
        wallet.on('value', snapshot => {
          var data = snapshot.val();
          var categories = [];
          var amounts = [];
          for (let i in data) {
            if(categories.includes(data[i].category){
                if(amounts[data[i].category] == undefined){
                   amounts[data[i].category]=1;
                }else{
                   amounts[data[i].category]++;
                }
            }
            categories.push(data[i].category)
          };
          console.log(amounts);
          this.setState({ loading: false, ok: true });
        })
      }
```